# How do you exit from a master function if child function fails

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a master function e.g. below that invokes child functions as shown below.

How do I exit the master function completely when one of the child functions fail?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_hide(
    IN p_hide_date character varying,
    IN p_hidedatexml character varying,
    IN p_cmp integer,
    IN p_taxin_no character varying)  RETURNS VOID AS $$

BEGIN
    PERFORM fn_hide_location(p_hide_date,p_cmp,p_taxin_no);
    PERFORM fn_hide_swlist(p_hide_date,p_cmp,p_taxin_no);
    PERFORM fn_hide_swruns(p_hidedatexml,p_cmp,p_taxin_no);
    PERFORM fn_hide_swdudes(p_hide_date,p_cmp,p_taxin_no);
    PERFORM fn_hide_chapter(p_hide_date,p_cmp,p_taxin_no);
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
COST 100;
```

The child functions being called within the "master function" essentially do the following

1. I have a list of id's that come from another source which is fed into a temp table
2. Existing records then have to be marked with a certain value say "hideme" that match the id's in the temp table.
3. I have another table that has a pre and post update count.
4. I write to this table, the count of all records before update and after update.
5. if the counts don't match then exit the function

Comment: If one of the function fails with an error, the whole function is aborted anyway. If you want to check for success or failure in data, the functions need to return someting, e.g. `success := fn_hide_location(...); if success then success := fn_hide_swlist(...)` and so on

Comment: Do you try to use `RAISE EXCEPTION` inside your functions? Here you have the posgresql documentation about RAISE EXCEPTION https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others you can throw/raise an error/exception in other functions

```
Raise Exception 'the Counts do not match first count %, second count %', count1, count2
```

This has the draw back of rolling back all  work done which you may not want

If you do not want to roll back the work done you can change the functions to Procedure which allow committing records and still raise exceptions 
[Create Procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html)  have to be using version 11 or higher

The other option is the return data from the functions beginning called and decide what to do from there

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_process(int, int) returns  int as $$
begin
--do some record processing
return 1;
end;
$$

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION master_process(int, int) returns  int as $$
declare
_result int ;
begin
select return_process(1,2) into _result;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Awesome response all. I’ll try out the suggestions made here and update here once I’ve refactored and tested the exit conditions . Essentially i would like to roll back everything if any of those functions fail.